# How to use forfiles to delete files without extension

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, delete-file

I am using *forfiles* to delete files older than 7 days from a specific directory using the following script found elsewhere on this forum:

```
forfiles -p "H:\E-drev" -m *.* /D -7 /C "cmd /c del @path"
```

This Works fine except I have some files with no extension eg. a file named *TA07l*. This file is not deleted. I have tried using `@fname` instead of `@path` but this does not help.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
forfiles /P "H:\E-drev" /M * /D -7 /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE if @ext==\"\" del @path"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `*` instead of `*.*` because otherwise it will search every files that contain a dot `.`

Update with few examples between `*` and `*.` and `*.*`:

```
copy nul _onefilewithoutext
copy nul _onefilewith.ext
mkdir _oneFolder
dir /b /a-d *.
_onefilewithoutext
```

`Forfiles` command

```
forfiles /M *. /C "cmd /C echo @relpath"
Error: File Type "*." not found.

forfiles /M * /C "cmd /C echo @relpath"
".\_onefilewith.ext"
".\_onefilewithoutext"
".\_oneFolder"

forfiles /M *.* /C "cmd /C echo @relpath"
".\_onefilewith.ext"

forfiles /M * /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE echo @relpath"
".\_onefilewith.ext"
".\_onefilewithoutext"

forfiles /M * /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE if @ext==\"\" echo @relpath"
".\_onefilewithoutext"
```

Comment: Pattern `*` matches _every_ item; perhaps `*.` might work (but I can't test right now)...

Comment: Yes, `*.` is how files without extensions are indicated.

Comment: @SomethingDark also not in `forfiles` case.